# Не могу понять UNION запросы

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте.

Появилась нужда извлекать одновременно данные из нескольких страниц, уложив всё это в один запрос. Ясно, что за это отвечает оператор UNION, но столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Когда извлекаю данные из одной таблицы, то при преобразовании данных в ассоциативный массив, всё данные оказываются на месте

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `subcat` = :subcat UNION SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `subcat` = :subcatt
```

Но при запросе вида:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = :id UNION SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id` = :id
```

Возвращает только данные, запрошенные в первой части запроса (из таблицы posts).

Собственно, прогуглив это дело толковой информации так и не нашел.

Пример кода вообще:

```
    $get = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = :id UNION SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id` = :id");
$get->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$get->execute();
$arr = $get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```

В общем, прошу помочь до конца понять UNION SQL запросы.

Comment: Возможно оба запроса во втором случае возвращают одинаковый набор данных и Union их фильтрует?

Comment: @lDrakonl а такое разве возможно при разной структуре таблиц?

Comment: Я не знаю php и не могу сказать, как он обрабатывает эту ситуацию. Но обычно в sql для UNION структура результата обоих запросов должна совпадать. Возможно в Вашем случае второй запрос просто не выполняется, так как получаемого результата не совпадает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNION это буквально **добавление строк** одного запроса к строкам другого при условии совпадения числа полей в этих запросах. Причем движок еще и проверит строки на полное совпадение и исключит дубли. Вы этого хотели?

Мне кажется вы не к месту применяете UNION. **Объединение таблиц делают через JOIN**. Типа:

```
SELECT p.*, c.*
FROM
  posts AS p JOIN
  comments AS c ON p.id=c.post_id
WHERE p.id=:id
```

Рекомендую прочесть любую книгу по любому диалекту SQL для понимания базовых вещей. https://www.google.ru/search?q=site%3Abooks.ru+SQL

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понял, что именно вы хотите вообще.

Для начала, запрос с `UNION` обязан содержать одинаковое число полей и одинаковые имена (можно использовать псевдонимы для этого) в каждом результате запросов, подлежащем объединению. У вас же выбрано всё (`SELECT *`), а структура таблиц неизвестна нам. Странно, что запрос вообще выполнился.

Как я понял из запроса, вы хотите ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ некие посты и некие комменты в один результат. Если да, то все что нужно сделать - это наделать псевдонимов и выбрать нужное количество полей в обоих запросах.

Если же вы хотите выбрать все посты и все комменты, относящиеся К ЭТИМ постам, то тут уже надо делать не ОБЪЕДИНЕНИЕ (`UNION`), а СОЕДИНЕНИЕ (`JOIN`), но это уже совсем другая история.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, метод prepare не позволяет использовать именованный параметр дважды. Вот похожая проблема: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777516/pdo-bindparam-with-multiple-named-parameters

Comment: Даже при разных параметрах происходит то же самое.
Пытаясь напрямую подставить данные для выборки, и отправив их через query всё равно возвращается только то, что запрашивали из первой таблицы.